# Two different panoid for the same photosphere Google Maps API JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i would appreciate some help in understanding why there are two different panoId patterns on Google StreetView.

I'm initializing photospheres with the following JavaScript code:

```
function initialize() {
    var pocetneKoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(44.81856295912351, 20.455767810344696);
    var pocetniPanoID = 'F:-By57yDKJr5M/WWfMHHWwYjI/AAAAAAAACXU/v1tk1TK02yEmBWGt2U4sMK1d_Uf3qdKmwCLIBGAYYCw';
    var mapOptions = {
            center: pocetneKoordinate,
            zoom: 0
    };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('panorama'),
            mapOptions);
        panorama = map.getStreetView();
        var panoOptions = {
            position: pocetneKoordinate,
            pano: pocetniPanoID,
            visible: true,
            pov: {
                heading: 41,
                pitch: 0,
                zoom:1,
            },
            clickToGo: false
        };
        panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
        // Create a StreetViewService object.
        var streetviewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
}
```

Just in case I pasted something wrong, working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/markovica/pcLjbmwk/

It all works great, but what confuses me is that I open the same panorama with two different PanoID strings, ex:

1. CAoSLEFGMVFpcE1EZGhWWFJzVzBTd0I4amlQOWtjdEJ3Z3MwVnYtNTZBbEJNRHBI
2. F:-By57yDKJr5M/WWfMHHWwYjI/AAAAAAAACXU/v1tk1TK02yEmBWGt2U4sMK1d_Uf3qdKmwCLIBGAYYCw

Besides that, on other linked photospheres, panorama.getPano() will return the pattern of the initial pano, and links are not exactly the same ([Screenshot showing differences in links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUV8o.png)) - there are some slight differences which I suppose are due to my recent edits.

But why are there two panoIDs for the same panorama and why are they behaving slightly different?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  Running the posted code I get a map (at 0,0), not a panorama.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I updated the post and added fiddle... however, I have no issue with coding, but with calling the same panorama with different strings and also having different links. 
I don't remember exactly how I got two different PanoID for the first panorama in the first place, but I did - I am trying to figure that out as well

Comment: I remembered how I got different strings:

Comment: one I got from initializing the google.maps.StreetViewPanorama object at exact lat/lng without fist creating the google.maps.Map object, and the other one (with F:) I got from this website http://www.ekreativa.com/pano-id-extract/ - I also get different links when managing photospheres in StreetView app on different devices (Tablet, Phone) - some deleted photospheres on one device apear on the other (published ones) as well.

Comment: I just deleted some photospheres and its links, and they are not visible using panoID pattern 2, but are visible with pattern 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of retrieving PanoID is by querying StreetView Publish API. It will give the first pattern. 
I used the API explorer:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/streetviewpublish/v1/